# How to solve this limit without L'Hoptial's $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\Delta x\right)-\frac{1}{2}}{\Delta x}$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to help out a friend with Calc 1 and am struggling to find this limit without using l'hopital's or the small angle approximation.

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\Delta x\right)-\frac{1}{2}}{\Delta x}$$

Which I can reduce to

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot\sin{\Delta x}}{2\cdot\Delta x}$$

Which is where I'm stuck. How can I simplify this further without the small angle approx or a taylor series expansion? Is there a way to do it with just trig identities?

Comment: First of all, you can pull out the $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  Then, we get $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\sin{\Delta x}}{\Delta x} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: Looks like a derivative to me...

Comment: Surely at this point the fact that $\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin (t)}t\right)=1$ is available.

Comment: It is a derivative, but my friend hasn't learned derivatives yet. I'm trying to do this strictly algebraically, and without any advanced math.

Comment: There's no way to do this problem without knowing the value of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} sin(x)/x$, and there's no way to find that 'strictly algebraically'. Your friend probably already learned this specific limit in class.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1?s=1|0.0000).

Comment: @nw How did you succeed to reduce the limit to $\;\frac{\sqrt3\sin\Delta_x}{2\Delta_x}\;$ ? For that you'd need to know how to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{\Delta_x\to 0}\frac{\cos\Delta_x-1}{\Delta_x}=0$$ so how do you do it without derivatives, Taylor, l'hospital and stuff?

Comment: @Timbuc I used the identity $\sin{(\phi+\theta)}=\sin{\phi}\cdot\cos{\theta}+\cos{\phi}\cdot\sin{\theta}$

Comment: @nw I was sure you did, yet that doesn't answer my question: how did you reduce the limit's expression to what you say you did?

Comment: simply plugging in 0 for $\Delta x$

Comment: @Timbuc Hey, **to prove** the derivatives of sinx and cosx, you need the two basic limits $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{\frac{\cos x - 1}{x}}$, so you cannot say that it is from derivatives...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$, so we get $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\sin(x)\right)$ evaluated at $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$. This is just $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

I think this is the intended method for the question, otherwise I don't think they would have chosen something that looks so similar to a derivative.